# mmap function always returning MAP_FAILED

Tags: c, mmap

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int* ptr = (int *) mmap(0x4096, sizeof(int)*1024, 1100, MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);
    fprintf(stdout, "%p\n", ptr);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not mmap\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My code is printing could not mmap, I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. My memory page's size is 4096 bytes so my address input is page size aligned too. What I want to do is allocate a memory space for 1024 integers using mmap on my specified address.

Comment: Remove the `fprintf` before the error check and use `perror` instead of `fprintf` inside the error check.  It will tell you *why* the call failed.

Comment: Do you have a regular file as standard input?

Comment: And the `prot` argument (`1100 = 0x44c`) is probably garbage -- why are you hard-coding it, instead of using `PROT_READ|...`, etc?

Comment: `0x4096 != 4096`.

Comment: Also, why do you want that particular address anyway?  Note that without `MAP_FIXED` it is only a hint and the OS may map your memory somewhere else.

Comment: As @HAL9000 notes you are trying to map file descriptor 0, i.e. standard input, which is very strange.  If you just want a block of memory not associated to any file, use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and set the `fd` argument to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by several people in the comments, I should be using MAP_ANONYMOUS, and haven't specified the memory location correctly. Using the following parameters worked,

```
mmap((void*) 0x0804a000, sizeof(int)*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);
```